# Ergodic and Non-ergodic (Equilibrium)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium, ergodicity

According to my textbook "Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics: An Integrated Approach (Cambridge by M. Scott Shell":

systems that are at equilibrium and isolated, are systems that obey the principle of equal a priori probabilities and are called ergodic.  Those that are not are called non-ergodic.

So could we have systems that are at equilibrium and non-ergodic?

Answer (score 2):

If the sentence you cite is the exact sentence in the book, it is unclear. One could be induced to think that every isolated system at equilibrium should be ergodic. The ergodic property concerns the *equal a priori probability* part.

An isolated system at equilibrium may not obey the principle of equal a priori probabilities (of the whole constant energy sub-manifold of the phase space). The simplest case is that of a system having at least a second constant of motion in addition to energy. The presence of an additional constant of motion implies partitioning the constant energy sub-manifold into a union of disjoint subsets. The probability of finding a system with a given value of the second constant of motion in the "wrong" subset of the constant energy submanifold is zero. At the same time, it is non-zero in the proper subset.

An example could be a perfect gas, i.e., a system of $N$ particles without mutual interaction and with elastic interactions with the boundaries. In the simple case of a two-dimensional rectangular box with coordinates aligned to the orthogonal sides, the total energy can be written as
$$
H = \sum_i \frac{p_{x,i}^2}{2m} + \sum_i \frac{p_{y,i}^2}{2m} = H_x+H_y.
$$
For such a system, $H_x$ and $H_y$ are separately constant of motion. Therefore, an isolated system starting with a given value of $H_x$ will stay forever in that subset of the constant $H$ hypersphere.

Answer (score 0):

The quotation is from p 53:

> Systems that are at equilibrium and obey the principle of equal a priori probabilities are called ergodic. Those that do not are non-ergodic.

This is not a good way to mix ergodicity and equilibrium, nor a good way to define ergodicity. A system is called *ergodic* if the time average of any mechanical property is equal to the ensemble average. In statistical mechanics (as in Gibbs) we always talk about *ensemble* averages*, not of time averages. Ergodicity is the *hypothesis* that the two averages are the same. There is no need for this hypothesis unless one wishes to reconcile the equations of motion with thermodynamics.

Are there equilibrium states that are non ergodic? The question is philosophical because proving ergodicity just based on the equations of motion alone is not possible. Still, this has no practical effect on the validity of statistical thermodynamics.

Comment: but is it true to assume that an isolated system that obeys the principle of equal a priori is at equilibrium? This is the definition presented by Stanford's statistical mechanic's book : https://web.stanford.edu/~peastman/statmech/statisticaldescription.html

Comment: The equal a priori hypothesis is a *postulate*. We don't know if it is true, we  will accept it as long as it leads to correct answers –and so far it has. Ergodicity, if true, would explain thermodynamics physically, which is why there is still some interest in the topic. But it would only *explain*, it would not produce any new equations for the calculation of entropy. The beauty of statistical mechanics is that a very simple postulate solves a very complex problem that kinetic theory and ergodicity cannot solve.